# pasting images on white background of size 39*39 randomly anywhere on white background

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I would like to generate a white image and then paste small 24*24 crops on (images) that white images but it should paste randomly anywhere on that white background.
How should I do it?

```py
import os

im1 = Image.open('data/src/white_image.jpg')
for path in dataset_paths:
    im2 = Image.open(path)
    back_im = im1.copy()
    back_im.paste(im2)
    back_im.save(f'data/dst/{os.path.basename(path)}')
```

also, it should paste randomly anywhere. please help!

Comment: Do you need to randomly paste all images from `dataset_paths` to the same `white_background`?

Comment: yeah, I need that only. but that white_background image should be used for each image. Like one image from dataset_path and white_background , after pasting It should save that image.
Then second image from dataset_path and white background and after pasting it should save for second image as well...like this it goes on for number of images in dataset_path @luangtatipsy

Comment: Maybe you can take inspiration from [this wonderful collage](https://github.com/rougier/scientific-visualization-book/blob/master/figures/coordinates/collage.png) obtained with [that quite simple code](https://github.com/rougier/scientific-visualization-book/blob/master/code/coordinates/collage.py).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```py
import random
from PIL import Image
import os
import glob

dataset_paths = [filename for filename in glob.glob('/home/user/Downloads/Dataset/training/cat/*.png')]

for i, path in enumerate(dataset_paths):
    bg_im = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(1024, 1024), color="white")
    img = Image.open(path).resize((24, 24))
    
    bg_width, bg_height = bg_im.size
    img_width, img_height = img.size
    max_x = bg_width - (img_width * 2)
    max_y = bg_height - (img_height * 2)

    if max_x < 0 or max_y < 0:
        print("image cannot be completely pasted on background image")
        continue 

    random_x = random.randint(0, max_x)
    random_y = random.randint(0, max_y)

    bg_im.paste(img, box=(random_x, random_y))
    bg_im.save(f'data/dst/{os.path.basename(path}')
```

PS. I recommend you to use `Image.new` for creating a background image instead of `Image.open`. You can replace size of the background image to whatever you need.

Comment: I tried but I get attribute error for line 'img = Image.open(path)' @luangtatipsy

Comment: I am using a list for dataset_path to list all images.

'from PIL import Image
import glob
dataset_paths = []
for filename in glob.glob('/home/user/Downloads/Dataset/training/cat/*.png'):
    im=Image.open(filename)
    dataset_paths.append(im)'

Comment: and also I would like to save new image by the name a pasted image. In a nutshell,. new image should have the pasted image name only

Comment: The variable `dataset_paths` in your code is not a list of paths in `str`, it is a list of PIL Image. The code I provided above, tries to read images from file paths which should be `str`.  I've just updated the code to address the error you faced.

Comment: Thanks, it works. just one issue. It paste multiple images on white background instead of 1 at a time. @luangtatispy

Comment: Ah! my bad, I understood that you need multiple images in the background image. I've updated that code.

Answer (score -1):

As you are using opencv you can just paste the image into the right position.

```
large_img[y_offset:y_end,x_offset:x_end] = small_img
```

More in depth explanations [can be found here](https://datahacker.rs/012-blending-and-pasting-images-using-opencv/)

Comment: I want to do it for like 100 images using loop, so i was asking about how to do it for 1000's of images.

Comment: That works for 100 images. All you need is to set the x and y offsets accordingly during the loop.